# isdigit() function doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int limit;
    float sum=0;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter the limit L: );
        scanf("%d",&limit);
        if(!isdigit(limit))
            break;
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
            sum+=(float)1/(i+1);
        }
        printf("Sum of the initial %d term(s): %f\n",limit,sum);
        sum=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this program calculates sigma of 1/n from n=1 to n=L(get input from user) if integer is entered, and exits when non-numerical character entered. but It seems this program doesn't work as I expected:
(I'm using LLVM compiler)

```
wak@waksys:~$./a.out
Enter the limit L: 5000
wak@waksys:~$
```

the program ends without yielding any results...so I think it there may be some problem at this part:

```
if(!isdigit(limit))
    break;
```

so I tried removing '!'.

```
if(isdigit(limit))
    break;
```

then I recompiled it and excuted it. It seems to work as expected but...

```
Enter the limit L: 5000
Sum of the initial 5000 term(s): 9.094514
Enter the limit L: 1000
Sum of the initial 1000 term(s): 7.485478
Enter the limit L: 1
Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: e
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
Enter the limit L: Sum of the initial 1 term(s): 1.000000
....
....
```

yes...It doesn't ends by infinited loop(actually, it's expected result by removing '!')

so it seems isdigit() function judges numbers like 5000, 1000 as not integer. Or is there any problem on my code?

Comment: `isdigit` is to determine whether the numeric character code. E.g`'0'`, `'1'`...

Comment: A basic, but well formed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit()`  checks the value of a single character to see if it is a digit (a character between `'0'` and `'9'`).

It is not used to check if `scanf("%d", ...)` has successfully scanned an integral value.    Check the return value from `scanf()` if you want to detect if it has succeeded in reading an integral value.   Doing that does not involve using `isdigit()` at all.

Answer (score 3):

`isdigit` tests if a character is a digit in the character set.  That is, '1' is a digit, but 'x' is not.  '1' has a numerical value as an integer (in ascii, it is 49)  When you enter 5000, scanf converts that to an integer value, and 5000 (mod 256) is likely not '0', '1', '2', ..., or '9' in the local character set.  Rather than using `isdigit`, check that scanf returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` does indeed take an `int` as an input, but that's only really so it can deal with things like `EOF` that can't fit into an `unsigned char`.

`isdigit` is used to inspect whether or not a particular character is a digit in the encoding used by your platform.

It's not designed to be used the way you are using it, so don't expect something sensible back from it.